# Any ideas on this mostly white and dark red set?

Tags: set-identification

I recently purchased quite a few Lego pieces from a neighbor. They are a bit of a mess with no instructions. I did find a couple bags that had not been opened. This is bag 2 and 3 and a couple smaller bags. I'm pretty sure bag one is already opened and in the mix of the others. Any ideas what set this could be. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on the White Wedge, Plate 6 x 12 Right, the Light Bluish Gray Technic, Steering Wheel Small, 3 Studs Diameter and Dark Red Wedge 3 x 4 with Stud Notches

I think these parts belong to

[75003-1 : A-Wing Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/75003-1/A-wing-Starfighter)

[image]